# Compiling boost 1.57 with intel compiler

Tags: c++, boost, intel

I tried to compile boost 1.57 with intel compiler and I got a error message:

```
*** argument error
* rule get-msvc-version-from-vc-string ( vc-string )
* called with: ()
* missing argument vc-string
```

Do you know how can I solve this problem.
Thank you

Comment: OS? ICC version? What parameters you provided for build?

Comment: OS: Windows 7 Enterprise x64. 
icl (intel compiler for windows): 14.0.0.103
I build it by bjam.exe toolset=intel

Comment: Does the [following](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/building-boost-with-intel-c-compiler-150) help?

Comment: No. :( I got same error message.

Comment: Could you paste the full command?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/building-boost-with-intel-c-compiler-150) the right command to use from an intel command prompt (after bootstrap.bat in order to compile b2.exe) is

**b2 toolset=intel-14.0-vc12**

instead of

**b2 toolset=intel**

14.0-vc12 because probably the version of your Intel compiler was 14.xx.xx (check it running icl command) and your Visual Studio version was 2012/2013.